# Hibernate+PostgreSQL: How to allow special characters inside tables?

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, jpa, jdbc

I'm using Hibernate with GWT and PostgreSQL. I have this TextArea which i pull text from it and the text might contain special characters like \r, \n...etc. For example, I have an entity:

```
@Entity
public class User {
  // Id & version
 // ...
  @Column
  public String name;
  @Column
  public String comment;
  //...getters & setters
}
```

So when i pull the text(which contains \n, \r) from CommentTextArea, store it in the comment field and persist the entity, i don't see the whole comment in the physical table.

Is there a way to "turn on" special characters in Hibernate?

Comment: You first have to tell whether it's a GWT or Hibernate/PostgreSQL issue. Is the `comment` _complete_ when received on the server-side? If yes, then it's not GWT; otherwise, it's not Hibernate or PostgreSQL.

Comment: It's probably not a Postgres problem, I can store and retrieve `\n` or `\r` without any problems.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Well the comment is not complete when i start inserting some new lines!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You store them using JPA or just plain SQL?

Comment: @FGraviton you don't answer the question: where are the additional lines _disappearing_? between client and server? (client bean has new lines, server bean doesn't) or when persisting the bean into the DB through Hibernate? (server bean has new lines, DB doesn't). In other words, debug, set breakpoints, inspect variables; you know, the usual stuff…

Comment: the server-side bean has the new lines but when i check the DB i don't see them!!

Comment: With plain SQL you should have no problem.  You can include whatever new lines you want.  In plain SQL you can just include them in quoted variables.  Your issue has to be a hibernate/JPA issue, which must be doing some funky encoding stuff.